# Owner vs Organization Adminstrator vs Billing Account Adminstrator

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform

I am lost in GCP role-land. I see two very similar looking roles:

**Owner** - Full access to all resources

**Organization Administrator** - Access to administer all resources belonging to an organization

Even with both roles, I *still*  couldn't access the billing accounts I hadn't personally created. So then I discovered a third permission that let me see those:

**Billing Account Administrator** - Authorized to see and manage all aspects of billing accounts.

1. What are the differences between these three?
2. When should I use them?
3. Is there a "superuser" role that allows me to do all the things?

Comment: Review the permissions that each role has. Example command: **gcloud iam roles describe roles/owner**

Comment: @JohnHanley, I don't have the CLI yet, but I will install that. That makes sense.

Comment: Learning the various CLI commands for IAM, Roles, Permissions, and identities will help you to understand how authorization works in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a "super user" role that will allow you to do all the things in GCP.

`Owner` is indirectly the super user role because with `Owner` role you can give yourself all the other permissions/roles that you need.

You can create a custom role (say `superuser`) and add [all GCP permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) into the role and assign it yourself, but this becomes a mundane task. This comes with a [limitation of 64 KB max role size](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas#:%7E:text=a%20custom%20role-,64%20KB,-Policies%20and%20role) and is left for experimentation.

Note: Organization level and project level roles are different, and owner of a project doesn't mean owner of an organization.

Comment: Never thought I'd miss AWS IAM. `"Action": "*"`.